# Call done() when all items in array have been processed

Tags: javascript, foreach, promise, settimeout

Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teqoz/z35p9jd0/)

```
[1,'a',2,'b'].forEach(function(item, i){
if (typeof item === 'number') {
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(item * 2);
},1000)
  } else if (typeof item === 'string') {
    console.log(item);
  }
})
done();

function done(){
    console.log('done');
}
```

This code returns:

```
a
b
done
2
4
```

How do I change the code so that it will call done() only when all items in array have been processed? 
i.e:

```
a
b
2
4
done
```

Comment: Why do you use setTimeout? Is it important or you just want strings and then numbers in array?

Comment: @MichałDąbrowski actually I just use setTimeout to emulate the problem. Actually I'm looking for a way to avoid this problem with another fabricjs function: object.clone(function(clone) {...})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Promise`s.
Wrap each process in a `Promise` that gets resolved when the process is finished.
Then wrap all the Promises in a `Promise.all`, which creates a new `Promise` that resolves once all the wrapped promises have resolved.
Then you call your `done` function.

```
var processes = [1,'a',2,'b'].map(function(item){
  if (typeof item === 'number') {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(item * 2);
        resolve();
      },1000);
    });
  } else if (typeof item === 'string') {
    console.log(item);
    return Promise.resolve(); // A Promise that resolves immediately
  }
});
Promise.all(processes).then(done);
```

[JSFiddle with your code modified as above](https://jsfiddle.net/541u4hya/1/)